# Upgrading and moving a site at the same time

Tags: ee1, upgrade

I have a huge website which gets a lot of traffic so it can't be down for very long. The site is still running 1.6.7 (I know, shame on me!). I'd like to move it to a new directory on my server and take my time upgrading the back end before going live with it. Do I need to install 1.6.7 in this new directory and then upgrade from there? I've been putting this off for ages because frankly, I'm terrified of it.

Also, assuming it takes me a month to get the new site the way I want it (I'm redesigning as well), when I switch to the new site, all of the information that's been added to the live site in the meantime will be missing. Is there any way to prevent this other than doing double entries using the two different dashboards?

Comment: You'll find some really helpful guidance in this answer on [EE1-2 upgrade methods.](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/ee1-to-ee2-upgrade/1324#1324) Also, here is [one approach](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5735/22) for mitigating issues related to your development/update copy getting out of sync with production

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to copy everything, the files and I make a duplicate database for the dev site. Make sure you upgrade your database settings in the config file! Then I do the upgrades on the duplicate site while the live site remains in tact.

I have done a couple of these EE1 to EE2 upgrades and they are tricky if you have 3rd party plugins involved. If you have structure installed, DO look at their instructions before you upgrade. You have a process to go through in EE1 before moving to EE2.

**Please PLEASE PLEASE make sure that you have a backup.**

As far as I know the live site content changes can not be updated to the new site, unless you copy them by hand.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to install 1.6.7 in this new directory and then upgrade from there? I've been putting this off for ages because frankly, I'm terrified of it.

I haven't tackled any big upgrades, but I think you need to copy the current site and perform the upgrade on that, test everything, update add-ons, and probably update some code where things have changed. I'd recommend doing this in dev, as I [outlined here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5956/move-expressionengine-from-development-to-live-same-server/5971#5971).

> Is there any way to prevent this other than doing double entries using the two different dashboards?

I suspect so. There is no way to merge the two. Your options are probably to keep up with duplicate entry, or document everything you did, and reproduce those steps on a fresh copy of the live database prior to re-launch, swapping that database in for the live database.